# How to best convert percentage to score in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to convert a percentage to a scoring system in Excel 2003, either using a built-in formula (preferable) or writing a custom function in VBA. The formula or function must accept a parameter allowing me to specify the maximum score.

For example, let's say there's a function called `Pct2Score(Pct As String, MaxScore As Integer)` that does just this.

**Pct2Score("65%", 4)** would return **3** because it would use this distribution:

```
0%-24.9% = 1
25-49.9% = 2
50-74.9% = 3
75-100% = 4
```

**Pct2Score("65%", 5)** would return **4** because it would use this distribution:

```
0-19.9% = 1
20%-39.9% = 2
40-59.9% = 3
60-79.9% = 4
80-100% = 5
```

And so on so forth. I'm hoping there is a built-in distribution formula in Excel that does exactly this so that I won't have to rely on VBA. It's even OK to use a combination of formulas to achieve this; the only limitation is that I need everything to be contained in one formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple formula (descriptive, not Excel) is simply:

```
1 + INT((Pct AS DOUBLE) * MaxScore / 100).
```

Using VBA:

```
Public Function Pct2Score(pct As String, MaxScore As Integer) As Integer
    Dim pctD As Double
    If (Right(pct, 1) = "%") Then pct = Left(pct, Len(pct) - 1)
    pctD = CDbl(pct)
    Pct2Score = 1 + Int(pctD * MaxScore / 100)
End Function
```

---

With a single formula you can do

```
=1+INT(A1*B1)
```

where A1 is Pct and B1 is MaxScore.

Comment: Hi Marco, 1 + INT(.65 * 100 / 4) = 17 and 1 + INT(.65 * 100 / 5) = 14. They should return 3 and 4, respectively.

Comment: @10basetom: no, that's not the formula. It's `1+INT(65*5/100)` or `1+INT(.65*5)`

Comment: I think I read your answer while it was being published so I was using the wrong info. Once I saw your final formula, everything worked like a charm. Thanks for providing a quick answer; I feel so dumb after seeing how simple the formula is (DOH!).

Comment: I'd just like to point out one minor issue I came across: if the percentage is 100%, then the resulting score would be one more than the maximum score. To account for this, I simply subtracted .001 from the percentile, e.g.: `1+INT((1-.001)*5)`