# Excel VBA RegEx Matching Percent

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I have a cell with text in it that read "Today's gain was 5.24% from yesterday". I would like to extract the percentage. I had previously written a UDF I called AnyNumber that I was modifying to AnyPercent. I checked my pattern on a couple sites, but it does not seem to work in Excel. Thanks!

```
Function AnyPercentage(Text As String) As Integer
With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
  .Pattern = "[0-9]{1,100}(\.[0-9]{1,100})?\%"
  If .test(Text) Then AnyPercentage = .Execute(Text)(0)
End With
End Function
```

Comment: And what doesn't work? *does not seem to work* is not a description of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're setting the function return type to an `integer`.

When the regexp finds the match, it returns a string in this case `5.24%`.

**You have a couple of alternatives:**

1. Look for just the digits in the regex pattern ([see this link](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html))
2. Use vba to extract the digits and then cast it as double or single (CDbl or CSng)

**Code for second alternative:**

```
Sub test()

    Dim anyResult As String
    Dim result As Double
    anyResult = AnyPercentage(Range("A1").Value)
    result = ExtractPercentage(anyResult)

End Sub

Function AnyPercentage(Text As String) As String
With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
  .Pattern = "[0-9]{1,100}(\.[0-9]{1,100})?\%"
  If .test(Text) Then AnyPercentage = .Execute(Text)(0)

End With
End Function


Public Function ExtractPercentage(ByVal PercentageString As String) As Double
    ' Credits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7885550/1521579
    If (Right(PercentageString, 1) = "%") Then ExtractPercentage = CDbl(Left(PercentageString, Len(PercentageString) - 1))
End Function
```

Have in mind that it is sensitive to your current regional settings (miles and decimals separator)

Answer (score 0):

With Regex:

```
Function AnyPercentage(Text As String) As Integer
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
      .Pattern = "[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\%"
      AnyPercentage = "-1"
      If .test(Text) Then
         AnyPercentage = Replace(.Execute(Text)(0), "%", "")
      End If
    End With
End Function
```

Without regex:

```
Sub GetPercentage()
    Dim a
    a = Split("Today's gain was 5.24% from yesterday%", "%")
    Dim Hsl
    If UBound(a) > 0 Then
       Hsl = a(0)
       a = Split(Hsl, " ")
       r = UBound(a)
       If IsNumeric(a(r)) Then
          Hsl = a(r) & "%"
       End If
    End If
    MsgBox Hsl
End Sub
```

In Function

```
Function GetPercentage(myVal as string) as string
    Dim a
    a = Split(myVal , "%")
    Dim Hsl
    If UBound(a) > 0 Then
       Hsl = a(0)
       a = Split(Hsl, " ")
       r = UBound(a)
       If IsNumeric(a(r)) Then
          Hsl = a(r) & "%"
       End If
    End If
    GetPercentage = Hsl
End Function
```